# Function inside a function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am working on a responsive design and made a function for the menu to change when its smaller then 540px (meant for mobile). It does change but I cant click the button and my guess is that it is because of the function inside a function.

This is the part that doesn't work:

```
  $('.menuknop').click(function(){
      $(".menu").slideToggle();
  });
```

Full code:

```
checkWidth(){
    var windowSize = $(window).width();
    if (windowSize < 540) {
        $(".menu").hide();
        $(".menuknop").show();

        $('.menuknop').click(function(){
            $(".menu").slideToggle();
        });
    }
    else {
        $(".menuknop").hide();
        $(".menu").show();
    }
}

//Execute function
checkWidth();
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
```

Comment: You shouldn't bind the event handler every time the window resizes. That could be the problem.

Comment: `checkWidth(){` -> `function checkWidth(){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5ajFn/)

```
 $('.menuknop').click(function(){
      $(".menu").slideToggle();
  });
function checkWidth(){
    var windowSize = $(window).width();
    if (windowSize < 540) {
        $(".menu").hide();
        $(".menuknop").show();
    }
    else {
        $(".menuknop").hide();
        $(".menu").show();
    }
}

$(window).resize(checkWidth);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what "can't click the button" means, but your code has at least one problem: every `resize` event that puts the width below 540px will attach an additional handler to the `click` event of `.menuknop`.

You could easily end up with hundreds of identical handlers like that when playing with the window, and the clicking the element would result in chaos.

You can solve this problem by reworking the logic:

```
checkWidth(){
    var windowSize = $(window).width();
    $('.menuknop').click(function(){
        var windowSize = $(window).width(); // calculate again
        if (windowSize < 540) {
            $(".menu").slideToggle();
        }
    });

    var lessThan540 = windowSize < 540;
    $(".menu").toggle(!lessThan540);
    $(".menuknop").toggle(lessThan540);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define click handler outside like this -

```
var windowSize = 0;
checkWidth() {
    windowSize = $(window).width();
    if (windowSize < 540) {
        $(".menu").hide();
        $(".menuknop").show();
    } else {
        $(".menuknop").hide();
        $(".menu").show();
    }
}

//Execute function
checkWidth();
$(window).resize(checkWidth);


$('.menuknop').click(function () {
    if (windowSize < 540) {
        $(".menu").slideToggle();
    }
});
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/vmcFH/